# Non Matching word removal in python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a text based string, and want to retain only specific words.

```
sample = "This is a test text. Test text should pass the test"
approved_list = ["test", "text"]
```

**Expected output:**

```
"test text Test text test"
```

I have read through a lot of `regex` based answers, unfortunately they do not address this specific issue.

Can the solution also be extended to a pandas series?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `pandas` for this.  Use the regex module `re`

```
import re

re.findall('|'.join(approved_list), sample, re.IGNORECASE)

['test', 'text', 'Test', 'text', 'test']
```

---

If you had a `pd.Series`

```
sample = pd.Series(["This is a test text. Test text should pass the test"] * 5)
approved_list = ["test", "text"]
```

Use the `str` string accessor

```
sample.str.findall('|'.join(approved_list), re.IGNORECASE)

0    [test, text, Test, text, test]
1    [test, text, Test, text, test]
2    [test, text, Test, text, test]
3    [test, text, Test, text, test]
4    [test, text, Test, text, test]
dtype: object
```

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful. The reason I stated about pandas, is because the `approved_list` need to be applied to each value of a `pd.Series`. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: @Drj Updated my post.